# How do I have to understand 参加させてほしい?

Tags: grammar, causation

会社で働いています。ビジネスマナーのセミナーの案内をもらいました。仕事に必要なので、**参加させてほしい**と課長におねがいします。

This excerpt is from my textbook. I don't understand why there is causative in the bold part. 
"...that you wish to be let taken part..." is how I would understand it literally. This sounds so complicated that I don't know wether I understood it correctly. I could let it pass as a humble formulation, but since it feels so circuitous, I wanted to ask for confirmation/correction here ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here 参加させてほしい literally means "I want 課長 to let me participate". To break down:

- 参加する: (intransitive verb) to participate
- 参加させる: ([causative form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/causepass) of 参加する) to make/let someone to participate
- 参加させて: the te-form of 参加させる
- te-form + 欲しい:  [I want someone to ～](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-japanese-grammar-41/)
- 参加させて欲しい: I want someone (=課長) to let someone (=me) to participate

Another similar and useful set phrase is ～(さ)せてください, which means "Let me ～", "Allow me to ～".

> - 考えさせてください。 Let me think about it.
> - 確認させてください。 Let me confirm.

Comment: is it more common to use 参加させて欲しい or 参加させてくれて欲しい？

Comment: 参加させてくれて欲しい sounds very weird to me (something like "I need to want to ～", maybe?)

Comment: hmmm I thought that させてくれる would always mean let me do something, maybe using ほしい will make it weird, I need to relearn this piece of grammar i guess